# AngularJS: Using a button to link to a page that is built using the ng-click directive on the button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button on a webpage

This is the button in my page verbSelect.html

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="app.verbPractice" ng-click="storeInfo(); generateSentences()">Submit</div>
```

Clicking on this button will link to a page called verbPractice.html. The link works, however, the page is not loading as expected. Both verbSelect.html and verbPractice.html are under the same controller called verbController

verbController

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('arabicApp')
    .controller('verbController', ['$scope', 'verbFactory', 'pronounFactory', 'attachedFactory', function($scope, verbFactory, pronounFactory, attachedFactory){
        //Gets verbs from server
        $scope.verbArray = verbFactory.getVerbs().query(
            function(response) {
                $scope.verbArray = response;
            }
        );

        //Gets pronouns from server
        $scope.pronouns = pronounFactory.getPronouns().query(
            function(response) {
                $scope.pronouns = response;
            }
        );

        $scope.attached = attachedFactory.getAttached().query(
            function(response) {
                $scope.attached = response;
            }
        );

        //Stores the array of selected verbs
        $scope.selectedVerbs = [];
        $scope.numSelectedVerbs = 0;

        //Searches theArray for name and returns its index. If not found, returns -1
        $scope.searchArray = function(theArray, name) {
            for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
                if (theArray[i].name === name) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        };

        //Adds verbs to selected list
        $scope.addToSelected = function(theVerb)  {
            var num = $scope.searchArray($scope.selectedVerbs, theVerb.name);
            var divToChange = document.getElementById("verbSelect_"+theVerb.name);
            if (num > -1) {                                             //Found. Remeove it from selectedVerbs
                $scope.selectedVerbs.splice(num, 1);
                divToChange.className = divToChange.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)listItemActive(?!\S)/g , '' );
                $scope.numSelectedVerbs = $scope.numSelectedVerbs - 1;
            } else {                                                    //Not found. Add it in
                $scope.selectedVerbs.push(theVerb);
                divToChange.className += " listItemActive";
                $scope.numSelectedVerbs = $scope.numSelectedVerbs + 1;
            }
        };

        //Stores how many practice questions the user wants
        $scope.howMany = 0;

        //Stores what tense of verbs the user wants
        $scope.verbTense = "Both";

        //Stores what form the user wants
        $scope.verbVoice = "Both";

        //Include commands?
        $scope.includeCommands = false;

        //Sentense that will be generated
        $scope.listOfSentences = [];


        $scope.generateSentence = function(isCommand, theTense, theVoice) {
            var sent = {"first": "", "second": "", "third": ""};

            var pronounPicker = Math.floor(Math.random()*14);
            var pronounToUse = pronouns[pronounPicker];
            sent.first = pronounToUse;

            var attachedPicker = Math.floor(Math.random()*14);
            var attachedToUse = attached[attachedPicker];

            var verbPicker = Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.numSelectedVerbs);
            var verbToUse = selectedVerbs[verbPicker].theTense.pronounToUse;

            if (isCommand === true) {
                sent.second = verbToUse;
            } else {
                sent.first = pronountToUse;
                sent.second = verbToUse;
                sent.third = attachedToUse;
                if (theVoice === "Passive") {
                    if (theTense === "Past") { sent.second = "were"; }
                    else { sent.second = "are"; }
                    sent.third = verbToUse;
                } else {
                    sent.second = verbToUse;
                    sent.third = attachedToUse;
                }
            }
            return sent;
        };

        $scope.storeInfo = function() {
            localStorage.setItem("howMany", $scope.howMany);
            localStorage.setItem("verbTense", $scope.verbTense);
            localStorage.setItem("verbVoice", $scope.verbVoice);
            localStorage.setItem("includeCommands", $scope.includeCommands);
        };

        $scope.getStoredInfo = function() {
            $scope.howMany = localStorage.getItem("howMany");
            $scope.verbTense = localStorage.getItem("verbTense");
            $scope.verbVoice = localStorage.getItem("verbVoice");
            $scope.includeCommands = localStorage.getItem("includeCommands");
        };

        //Generates sentences using the variables from verbSelect
        $scope.generateSentences = function() {
            $scope.getStoredInfo();
            console.log($scope.howMany);
            var tensePicker;
            var voicePicker;
            var doCommand;
            var rand;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.howMany; i++) {
                //Picks the verb tense
                if ($scope.verbTense === "Both") {
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random());
                    if (rand === 0) { tensePicker = "Past"; }
                    else { tensePicker = "Present"; }
                } else {
                    tensePicker = $scope.verbTense;
                }

                //Picks the verb voice
                if ($scope.verbVoice === "Both") {
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random());
                    if (rand === 0) { voicePicker = "Active"; }
                    else { voicePicker = "Passive"; }
                } else {
                    voicePicker = $scope.verbVoice;
                }

                //If the voice is passive, use past tense
                if ($scope.verbVoice === "Passive") { $scope.verbVoice = "Past"; }

                //Determines if the sentence will be a command sentence or not
                if ($scope.includeCommands === true) {
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                    if (rand === 0) { doCommand = true; }
                    else { doCommand = false; }
                } else {
                    doCommand = false;
                }

                var sentence = $scope.generateSentence(doCommand, tensePicker, voicePicker);
                console.log(sentence);
                $scope.listOfSentences.push(sentence);
            }
        };
    }])

;
})();
```

The following variables are set using ng-model in the verbSelect.html page

```
howMany
verbVoice
verbTense
includeCommands
```

I thought that these would carry over to the next page. However, I have a feeling that the variables are reset when the page is changed (is that right?).

This is why I used the storeInfo() and getStoredInfo() functions. I thought that this way, I would be able to carry those variables over to the next page.

This is what my verbPractice.html page looks like

```
<div ng-controller="verbController">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="sentence in listOfSentences">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>{{sentence.first}} {{sentence.second}} {{sentence.third}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I run my application and click the button on verbSelect.html, it links to verbPractice.html but the page shows up blank. Even the console.log($scope.howMany) lines don't show up in the log, and neither do the consol.log(sentence). I think this means that generateSentences() isn't being called when the button is clicked for some reason.

Could someone help me understand why my page is showing up blank and how to fix it? Why are the functions nto running when the button is clicked?

Thanks and sorry for the long post

Answer (score 1):

Add `$scope` to reach `pronouns`. This will lead function `generateSentence` fails in error.

```
var pronounToUse = $scope.pronouns[pronounPicker];
var attachedToUse = $scope.attached[attachedPicker];
var verbToUse = $scope.selectedVerbs[verbPicker].theTense.pronounToUse;
```

While defining `state` using `ui-router`, there is no need to use `ng-controller` in template any more.

Comment: Thanks. Can't beleive I didn't see that. I fixed that line and added $scope. to the attached and selectedVerbs variables as well. However, the page still shows up blank. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: @The_Questioner I see you are using `ng-controller` in the new page, did you defined states using uiRouter? If so, you may have to remove `ng-controller` too.

Comment: Thank You! The function seems to be working now. So when I'm using a uiRouter, I can't put ng-controller in any html file?

Comment: @The_Questioner yes, this is because you have binded the controller while define states.